# Spring 3 MVC form binding with java.util.List, including form errors and validation with bindingResult

Tags: forms, list, binding, spring-mvc, validation

I'm struggling to find good information about Spring forms (including validation) with List objects, particularly when not relating to select boxes or checkboxes etc.

I want a form object like:

```
public class MyForm {
    private List<String> values;
    public List<String> getValues() { return this.values; }
    public void setValues(List<String> values) { this.values = values; }
}
```

JSP:

```
<form:form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/something" commandName="myForm">
    ...
    <c:forEach var="unused" items="${myForm.values}">
        <div><form:input path="values" /><form:errors path="values" /></div>
    </c:forEach>
    ...
</form:form>
```

Controller:

```
...
for (String value : myForm.getValues()) {
    if (! isValidCode(value)) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("values", "invalid.code", "Code unknown!");
    }
}
...
```

When I submit the form, I can see that the values entered come through in the java.util.List correctly.

When the form is rendered again:
 a) each input field has the same value (the last value entered), and
 b) the form:errors shows multiple error messages for every fields, including valid values.

Is there something wrong with how I c:forEach loop over the list that results in each input field getting the same value?

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
    if (! isValidCode(value)) {
        bindingResult.rejectValue("values[" + i + "], "invalid.code", "Code unknown!");
    }
```

And:

```
<c:forEach var="unused" items="${values}" varStatus="status">
    <div><form:input path="values" /><form:errors path="values[${status.index}]"  /></div>
</c:forEach>
```

This specifically does not work, and I've tried a number of variations of this and can't seem to get it working - any ideas/help would be much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Both form tags should have the same path:

```
<c:forEach items="${values}" varStatus="status">
    <div><form:input path="values[${status.index}]" /><form:errors path="values[${status.index}]"  /></div>
</c:forEach>
```